# How can I simulate an unresponsive file descriptor?

Tags: files, file-descriptors, nas, write

We have an application that writes to a log file. In the prod environment, the log file directory is mapped to a NAS:

```
192.168.1.10:/storage/app/log 2554360832 11844608 2412762112   1% /usr/local/app/log
```

I've been told that on a few occasions the NAS has gone down, which caused our application to block indefinitely when attempting to write to the log file.

I'd like to try to reproduce this to be certain that is what happened, and also to be able to test a fix. But we don't have a NAS in our dev environment.

Is there any way to cause a file descriptor to become unresponsive so that an attempt to write to it will block indefinitely?

Comment: [I assume that your NAS is mounted over nfs] Your application is blocked in an uninterruptible sleep (`D`) in that case, and once trapped in that hole, there's NOTHING your app can do about it. You can't even kill it. You can try mounting the nfs filesystem with the `soft` option (and also tweak the `timeo` and `retrans` options) which will cause an I/O error instead of trapping it in a uninterruptible sleep. But, as mentioned in the manapge, that may result in slient data corruption.

Comment: To answer your stated Q, I do have a fuse filesystem able to generate all kind of errors and weird conditions -- if I tidy it up and write some docs I may put it somewhere. But there are probably already lots of similar stuff already published. A readily available way to test that is by mounting a file system exported by a system running in a qemu vm, and stopping/restarting the emulation from the qemu console with `stop`/`cont`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a named pipe but do not open it for reading:

```
$ mkfifo /tmp/test-fifo
$ echo a > /tmp/test-fifo
```

Comment: That will block when trying to open the fifo, ie. before the open returned any fd which would become "unresponsive". And anyways, a _blocking_ write to a pipe/fifo/socket/etc would ABSOLUTELY not simulate a _non-blocking_ write to regular file exported from a remote fs.

Comment: OP asked `How can I simulate an unresponsive file descriptor?`, and this question answers it. OP may try to come up with a solution that could prevent an indefinite block, for example by implementing a timeout.

Comment: Your answer does NOT simulate an unresponsive file descriptor, even when assuming a broader Q, and not the scenario described in the OP (a NAS which has gone down).

Comment: @mosvy: do you mean that OP is looking only for solutions in which file has been opened successfully using `open()` or something, fd points to a valid resource but this resource becomes unavailable before  `write()` is called, causing it to block indefinitely?

Comment: Exactly. Especially when the opened file is a regular file, where neither a `write(2)` nor a `read(2)` does block, and on which `select(2)` & co always return ready.

Answer (score 0):

Open one of these with nothing on the other end.

- A named pipe.
- An anonymous pipe.
- An internet socket.
- ...

You could also run a service locally. You could even run them in docker (or over containerisation or virtualisation). This is preferred, as you will have no idea what differences there are in the other options.

Comment: [ditto](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/579224/how-can-i-simulate-an-unresponsive-file-descriptor#comment1078111_579227)